# BSONObjectIDFormat in trait BSONFormats is deprecated

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am using Reactive Mongo version 0.11.11 and I want to implement a method in my DAO which counts all documents by `_id`.

Here is my DAO:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject
import models.auth.{Team, Player}
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json._
import reactivemongo.bson._
import reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection

import scala.concurrent.Future

trait TeamDao {
  def find(_id: BSONObjectID): Future[Option[Team]]

  def find(name: String): Future[Option[Team]]

  def save(team: Team): Future[Team]

  def link(player: Player, team: Team): Future[Team]

  def update(team: Team): Future[Team]

  def count(team: Option[Team] = None): Future[Int]

  def count(_id: BSONObjectID): Future[Int]

  def countAllPlayersWithTeam(team: Team): Future[Int]
}

class MongoTeamDao @Inject()(reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi) extends TeamDao {

  val players = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[JSONCollection]("players")
  val teams = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[JSONCollection]("teams")

  def find(_id: BSONObjectID): Future[Option[Team]] = teams.find(BSONDocument("_id" -> _id)).one[Team]

  def find(name: String): Future[Option[Team]] = teams.find(Json.obj("name" -> name)).one[Team]

  def save(team: Team): Future[Team] = teams.insert(team).map(_ => team)

  def link(player: Player, team: Team) = for {
    _ <- players.update(Json.obj("_id" -> player.id), Json.obj("$push" -> BSONDocument("teams" -> team._id)))
    team <- find(team._id.get)
  } yield team.get


  def update(team: Team) = for {
    _ <- teams.update(BSONDocument("_id" -> team._id), BSONDocument("$set" -> BSONDocument("name" -> team.name)))
    team <- find(team._id.get)
  } yield team.get


  def count(team: Option[Team] = None): Future[Int] = {
    val tmpTeam: Team = team.getOrElse {
      return teams.count()
    }
    teams.count(Some(Json.obj("name" -> tmpTeam.name)))
  }

  def count(_id: BSONObjectID): Future[Int] = {
    teams.count(Some(Json.obj("_id" -> _id)))
  }

  def countAllPlayersWithTeam(team: Team): Future[Int] = {
    players.count(Some(Json.obj("teams" -> team._id)))
  }

}
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
value BSONObjectIDFormat in trait BSONFormats is deprecated: Use [[reactivemongo.play.json.BSONFormats.BSONObjectIDFormat]]
[error]     teams.count(Some(Json.obj("_id" -> _id)))
```

I tried to replace the `count` method with:

```
def count(_id: BSONObjectID): Future[Int] = {
 teams.count(Some(BSONDocument("_id" -> _id))) 
}
```

But then I get the following compile error:

```
[error]  found   : reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument
[error]  required: MongoTeamDao.this.teams.pack.Document
[error]     (which expands to)  play.api.libs.json.JsObject
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     teams.count(Some(BSONDocument("_id" -> _id)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `JSONCollection` and BSON values.

It's recommanded that you either use the [JSON serialization](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/json/overview.html) with `JSONCollection`, or you use the default [BSON serialization](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/bson/overview.html) with `BSONCollection`.

> The deprecation message is a warning indicating to use the separate JSON library, instead of the former types previously included in the Play plugin.

A `BSONCollection` can be resolved from the Play plugin as follows.

```
reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection[BSONCollection]("players"))
```

> The functions `MongoConnection.(db|apply)` and/or `ReactiveMongoApi.db` are deprecated, and the equivalent `.database` must be used (which returns `Future[DefaultDB]` instead of `DefaultDB`).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am using Silhouette and I need to persist `LoginInfo` as part of a `Player` document. Now the problem is, that in the class `LoginInfo` there is only `implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[LoginInfo]` and therefore I get a type error, because I am now handling BSON and not JSON. Do you have any idea if I can make a BSON out of a JSON or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, the only reason why I am handling BSON now is because I need to map somehow `_id`. Unfortunately, there is no JSON substitute for `BSONObjectID`, is there?

Comment: If you read the [doc](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/json/overview.html), you can see that when using JSON, the representation for a `BSONObjectID` is a `JsObject` with `$oid`, and that conversion for that is provided by `import reactivemongo.play.json._`

Comment: Thank you for your help!